# ItemizedOverlay cannot be solved to a variable

Tags: android, google-maps

Here is the code where I use [ItemizedOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay), in GPSTracker.java:

```
Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red);
OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
mapView.invalidate();
```

Here is the full code of MyItemizedOverlay.java:

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context ctx) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));

}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

public void clear() {

    mOverlays.clear();
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView){

    return false;
}}
```

How do I fix the error?

Comment: did you import the class? Why are you using the old google maps and not v2?

Comment: i imported the class. and yes, damn! the problem is in old google maps. thank you. how do i make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If not already done, you should import the class.
2. You are using the old Google Maps and not v2. v2 does not have `ItemizedOverlay`.

Comment: it was an old tutorial. gotta find another one

Comment: take a look here, there are a bunch of tutorials http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/12/a-simple-example-using-google-maps.html